# Average value of the square of the number of heads in a sequence of coins.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Given a sequence of $n$ coins, of which $k$ are heads, what is the average value of $k^2$?
Each coin may be either heads or tails, with even odds.

To phrase it differently, over the $2^n$ possibilities for the sequence, what is the total sum of each value of $k^2$?

I have calculated this average as $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k^{2}}{2^n}$

I know the average value turns out to be $\frac{n(n+1)}{4}$, but I do not know how to derive this.

Answer (score 3):

The mean and variance of a single coin toss are $1/2$ and $1/4$ respectively. For $n$ coin tosses, these will be $n/2$ and $n/4$. Then we use the identity $\sigma^2=\langle k^2\rangle-\langle k \rangle^2$ to get $\langle k^2\rangle= n(n+1)/4$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain what the ⟨⟩ notation means?

Comment: @Dash-Eight8Hyphen-8 It's the average value of the quantity inside the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I think the trick is to use the function $f(x) = (1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k$, explicit the derivatives and computes it at $x = 1$.

for example, the first one is $f'(x) = n (1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} k x^{k-1}$ so you have the result :
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom{n}{k} = n 2^{n-1} $$

next one is $ f''(x) = n (n - 1) (1+x)^{n-2} = \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} k (k-1) x^{k-2} = \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} k^2 x^{k-2} - \sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k} k x^{k-2} $. for x = 1, you get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{1} + \frac{n (n-1)}{4} 2^n + \frac{n}{2} 2^n - \binom{n}{1} = \frac{n (n+1)}{4}2^n$$

PS : careful of the indices, starting at $k=2$ with second derivative, so we add the first term $\binom{n}{1}$ for $k=1$ in each sums, which still cancels out.

Comment: Thanks, that's an elegant way to find the value.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!\;k^2}{k!(n-k)!}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n\;(n-1)!\;k}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}=$$
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}\frac{n\;(n-1)!\;(l+1)}{l!(n-1-l)!}=n\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose l}+n\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose l} l;$$
$$\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose l} l=\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!\;l}{l!(n-1-l)!}=\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)(n-2)!}{(l-1)!(n-1-l)!}=$$
$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-2} \frac{(n-1)(n-2)!}{m!(n-2-m)!}=(n-1)\sum_{m=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose m};$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} k^2=n\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose l}+n(n-1)\sum_{m=0}^{n-2} {n-2\choose m}=$$
$$n\cdot 2^{n-1}+n(n-1)\cdot 2^{n-2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{4}\cdot 2^{n}$$